# What does the phrase "返す刀" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I've tried looking this up in English--Japanese dictionaries with no luck. I did however get a few results in monolingual dictionaries but I still don't understand what it's supposed to mean and in what context it may be used. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I saw it in a book which had a collection of short stories, since I don't own the book I don't have it in front of me right now to put the full text up, but from what I remember there was two characters having a conversation (lets call them A and B), A brings up the name of a dear friend to B who passed away not too long ago which is understandably upsetting for him, I can vaguely remember "Bは返す刀で痛いところ~"  "B was hit in a place that hurts[返す刀で]" in regards to what A just said.

Answer (score 7):

「返{かえ}す刀{かたな}」 is a set phrase meaning "**attempting an attack on a second or different party on an impetus/momentum gained from the success of one's attack on the first or original party**".

In other words, your second attack was encouraged by the success of your first.

It does not have to be a physical attack, let alone a sword attack as 「刀」 means "sword".  The expression is often used to describe a ***verbal*** attack.

The expression is used mostly adverbially in the form of 「返す刀**で** + Verb Phrase」.

Finally, I feel I would need to mention the fact that this phrase is quite often used incorrectly by us native speakers.  That incorrect meaning is "**counterattack**" or "**fighting back**".

[This page](http://yourei.jp/%E8%BF%94%E3%81%99%E5%88%80) will give you some example sentences.

Comment: +1, 動作としては[こういう](https://youtu.be/vkyV0JGMQnY) イメージですね